# Generate id for durations with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with dates (Time), I consider one duration as consecutive times of 1s:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c("2021-12-01 01:01:01","2021-12-01 01:01:02","2021-12-01 01:01:03","2021-12-01 01:01:05","2021-12-01 01:01:06"))
```

I would like to generate an Id for each duration like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c("2021-12-01 01:01:01","2021-12-01 01:01:02","2021-12-01 01:01:03","2021-12-01 01:01:05","2021-12-01 01:01:06"),Id = c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

With dplyr...
Thank you

Comment: could you please give an example of this  'I consider one duration as consecutive times of 1s'

Comment: First be sure to have real timestamps, not strings. You need to use `as.POSIXct` (or optionally one of several packages intended to help) in order to convert to the `POSIXt` class you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front:

```r
cumsum(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(as.POSIXct(data$Time)), units = "secs") > 1L))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

First, you should really be working with *real timestamps* and not strings. If you're doing anything else with your `Time` field, it is almost certainly going to be a number-like operation, so you should do this up-front with

```r
data$Time <- as.POSIXct(data$Time)
```

This works easily here because they are well-formed along the default format of `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`; see [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for the `%`-codes.

From here, you want to keep track of when a difference in time is more than 1 second. The differencing is easy enough with:

```r
as.numeric(diff(data$Time), units = "secs")
# [1] 1 1 2 1
```

Really, the key operator is `diff`, but it *can* report minutes or hours or such if the data is widely-enough spaced; there's an internal heuristic for that. Wrapping it in `as.numeric(., units="secs")` forces it to always be in seconds.

From here, we need a cumulative sum of when it is above 1, ergo `> 1L`, so `cumsum(. > 1L)`.

Note that we have input length 5 but output length 4, this makes sense realizing that *differences* are between two elements. We force the first difference-test to be `TRUE`. If you have since changed to `POSIXt`-class, then the original code is reduced slightly to be

```r
cumsum(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(data$Time), units = "secs") > 1L))
```

and therefore to store it as `Id`,

```r
data$Id <- cumsum(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(data$Time), units = "secs") > 1L))
```

Comment: @r2evans superb